# jQuery ul li toggle menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my HTML code here :

```
<ul class="main-block">

 <li class="firstLevel">
   <a href="#category">EXAMPLE CATEGORY 1</a>
     <ul class="dijete">
       <li class="child">
          <a href="some-sub-category.html">EXAMPLE SUB-CATEGORY 11.</a>
       </li>
       <li class="child">
          <a href="some-sub-category.html">EXAMPLE SUB-CATEGORY 1.1</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
 </li>

 <li class="firstLevel">
   <a href="#category">EXAMPLE CATEGORY 2</a>
     <ul class="dijete">
       <li class="child">
          <a href="some-sub-category.html">EXAMPLE SUB-CATEGORY 2.1</a>
       </li>
       <li class="child">
          <a href="some-sub-category.html">EXAMPLE SUB-CATEGORY 2.2</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
 </li>

</ul>
```

My jQuery code for `toggle()` is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(function() {
        $j('li.firstLevel').click(function(){
            if($j('ul.dijete').hasClass('active')){
                $j(this).find('ul.dijete').removeClass('active');
            }else{
                $j(this).find('ul.dijete').addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But when I am on one category EXAMPLE 1 (active or clicked already) and chose to click on another EXAMPLE 2 - the first one does not close, so as the other second that I clicked doesn not open.

Why is that hide-show doesn't work?

Why I can not show second `sub-menu` and hide first one while I am currently on first (not working in both ways)?

Comment: Actually I am adding a CSS class, instad using jQuery toggle();? 
Class has CSS style display:block (default none)
OR should I use hide() show() for displaying child ul content?

Comment: try using jquery's toggle function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery toggleClass if else not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881168/jquery-toggleclass-if-else-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/70/)**

You could use `toggleClass()` function instead and before adding `active` class to the clicked item you should remove it from other items with class `dijete` using :

```
$('ul.dijete').removeClass('active');
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Working snippet

```js
$('li.firstLevel').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $('ul.dijete').removeClass('active');
  $(this).find('ul.dijete').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-block">

  <li class="firstLevel">
    <a href="#category">EXAMPLE CATEGORY 1</a>
    <ul class="dijete">
      <li class="child">
        <a href="some-sub-category.html">EXAMPLE SUB-CATEGORY 11.</a>
      </li>
      <li class="child">
        <a href="some-sub-category.html">EXAMPLE SUB-CATEGORY 1.1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="firstLevel">
    <a href="#category">EXAMPLE CATEGORY 2</a>
    <ul class="dijete">
      <li class="child">
        <a href="some-sub-category.html">EXAMPLE SUB-CATEGORY 2.1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="child">
        <a href="some-sub-category.html">EXAMPLE SUB-CATEGORY 2.2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function() {
    $j('li.firstLevel').click(function(){
        $j(this).children('ul.dijete').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```