# jQuery toggleClass if else not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cannot get working jQuery toggleClass() within if-else condition.

My HTML code is:

```
<ul>
  <li class="firstLevel">
   <a href="#main_cat_01">MAIN CATEGORY #1</a>
     <ul class="dijete">
       <li>
          <a href="#subt_cat_01">SUB CATEGORY #1</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="firstLevel">
   <a href="#main_cat_02">MAIN CATEGORY #2</a>
     <ul class="dijete">
       <li>
          <a href="#subt_cat_02_01">SUB CATEGORY #1</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

My CSS code is:

```
ul.dijete {
    display: none;
}

.vidimte{
    display: block;
}
```

My JavaScript code is:

```
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(function() {
        $j('li.firstLevel').click(function(){
            if($j(this).children("ul.dijete").hasClass("vidimte")){
                $j(this).children("ul.dijete").toggleClass('vidimte'); //visible
                $j(this).find("ul.dijete").prev("li.firstLevel a").css({
                    "background-image":'url(URL_TO_THE_IMAGE_OPEN)',
                    "background-position":"right center",
                    "display":"block",
                    "background-repeat":"no-repeat"
                });
            }else{ // else add image close and display none
                $j(this).find('ul.vidimte').prev("li.firstLevel a").css({
                    "background-image":'url(URL_TO_THE_IMAGE_CLOSE)',
                    "background-position":"right center",
                    "display":"block",
                    "background-repeat":"no-repeat"
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I cannot get this working.

Do I have to use on.('click) method for that?

Any ideas?

Thanks for help or any information!

Comment: Looks like [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), `ul.dijete` is more specific than `.vidimte`, so adding the class does nothing. One solution would be to toggle both -> `..toggleClass('vidimte dijete')`

Comment: Why are you using toggleClass() rather than removeClass(), given that you call it inside an if that checks that the class is already present? Also, your if removes the class, but your else doesn't add it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Thanks for sharing ideas!

Solution worked for me:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function() {
    $j('li.firstLevel').on('click', function() {
        if($j(this).closest("li").children("ul.dijete").length){
            $j(this).children("ul.dijete").toggleClass('vidimte');


            if($j(this).children("ul.dijete").hasClass("vidimte")){
                $j(this).find("ul.dijete").prev("li.firstLevel a").css({
                    "background-image":'url(http://www.v-tac.hr/wp-content/themes/vtac/images/stories/customfilters/open.png)',
                    "background-position":"right center",
                    "display":"block",
                    "background-repeat":"no-repeat"
                });
            }else{
                $j(this).find('ul.dijete').prev("li.firstLevel a").css({
                    "background-image":'url(http://www.v-tac.hr/wp-content/themes/vtac/images/stories/customfilters/closed.png)',
                    "background-position":"right center",
                    "display":"block",
                    "background-repeat":"no-repeat"
                });
            }
        }
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

the `.toggleClass()` function is used to remove or add classs, that is said in your question in your `else` expression you didn't remove or add the class back;
add `$j(this).children(".dijete").toggleClass('vidimte')` to `else`
but I think your goal is that click the link then show/hide the sub link also change background. then codes link these:
`$j(this).children('ul').toggleClass('dijete vidimte')`